# Better Way of Debugging Cython Packages

Tags: python, cython

I currently use Cython to build a module that is mostly written in C. I would like to be able to debug quickly by simply calling a python file that imports the "new" Cython module and test it. The problem is that I import GSL and therefore pyximport will not work. So I'm left with "python setup.py build; python setup.py install" and then running my test script.

Is this the only way? I was wondering if anyone else uses any shortcuts or scripts to help them debug faster?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just throw all the commands I need to build and test into a shell script, and run it when I want to test. It's a lot easier than futzing with crazy Python test runners.